# Zeros of a finite Fourier integral implies the same for all derivatives

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $\phi(x)\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be an infinitely differentiable finite function with support $\operatorname{supp} \phi \subset [-c,c]$ and let $\mu_0$ be a zero of the function

$$\Phi(\lambda)=\int_{-c}^{c} \phi(x) \exp(-i \lambda x) dx \tag{1}$$

Then
$$ \int_{-c}^{c}\sum_{j=0}^{n} c_j \phi^{(j)}(x)\exp(-i \mu_0 x) dx=0 \tag{2}$$

where $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer and $c_j$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$ are arbitrary complex numbers.

How to prove this proposition? Should I use integration by parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should integrate by parts. Be careful to treat the case $\mu_0=0$ separately (this case only needs the fundamental theorem of calculus). For $\mu_0\ne 0$, 
$$\begin{split}0&=\int_{-c}^{c} \phi(x) \exp(-i \mu_0 x)\, dx 
\\&= -i\mu_0^{-1}\int_{-c}^{c} \phi'(x) \exp(-i \mu_0 x)\, dx 
\\&= (-i)^2\mu_0^{-2}\int_{-c}^{c} \phi''(x) \exp(-i \mu_0 x)\, dx \end{split}$$
and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing the question and providing the solution.  Best